# Arrange the values in their absolute

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need some help please in Excel.

I want to know how should I need arrange this values but in their absolute?
-10% 3% 4% -20%

I need that the output will be like
20%,10%,4%,3%

[image]

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT YELL! Typing in all caps is considered yelling.  Please [edit] the post to remove the all caps.

Comment: [This](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1284-excel-sort-by-absolute-value.html) is the top result I get from Google. I think it answers your question? If not please edit your question to explain why not.

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/507303-how-do-you-convert-an-entire-column-into-absolute-value.html) is what you mean, to convert the column to absolute values?

Comment: I was trying to do =LARGE(ABS(EMPLOYMENT!$E$2:$E$97),2) but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula `SORT()` then use:

```
=SORT(ABS(EMPLOYMENT!$E$2:$E$97),,-1)
```

[image]

---

If not use put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,ABS(EMPLOYMENT!$E$2:$E$97)),ROW($ZZ1))
```

[image]

Comment: @SIMONA What happens when you type the formula and watch the intellisense that shows the meaning and the options for the parameters? If you applied your reading skills, some things might not need to be asked.

Comment: 14.0% 2012
13.1% 2004
11.7% 2007
11.5% 2013
11.1% #N/A    My last question is when I want to searching for the data (11.1%) in another table and  taking the year of this value.   what can i do if its performance as a -11.1% in the another table? Thanks for the helping!

Comment: @SIMONA new questions get new posts.

Answer (score 0):

*These formula fixes the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `M176`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(ABS(INDEX($K$176:$K$185,MATCH(LARGE(INDEX(ABS($K$176:$K$185)+(ROWS($K$176:$K$185)-ROW($K$176:$K$185))/10^5,0),ROWS(M$176:M176)),INDEX(ABS($K$176:$K$185)+(ROWS($K$176:$K$185)-ROW($K$176:$K$185))/10^5,0),0))),"")
  ```
- Formula in cell `N176`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(ABS(INDEX($K$176:$K$185,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX(ABS($K$176:$K$185)+(ROWS($K$176:$K$185)-ROW($K$176:$K$185))/10^5,0),ROWS(N$176:N176)),INDEX(ABS($K$176:$K$185)+(ROWS($K$176:$K$185)-ROW($K$176:$K$185))/10^5,0),0))),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- Cell format on Column `M` and `N` are, **Percentage** and **Decimal place is 1**.
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*